# remove part of a word after apostrophe

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have

```
df<-c("That's","you're", "'am")
```

and I would like to remove the part of a word after and including the apostrophe which should return

```
c("That", "you", "")
```

`tidyverse` solution or a solution usable within a pipe `|>` structure preferable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `'` and whatever follows it, using `str_replace` in `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(df, "'.*", "")  
#[1] "That" "you"  ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Using R base `sub`

```
> sub("'.*", "", df)
[1] "That" "you"  ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example data only has one word per string. If you also need it to work for strings containing multiple words then use:

```
gsub("'\\w*\\b","",df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `trimws` in `base R`

```
trimws(df, whitespace = "'.*")
[1] "That" "you"  ""
```